# How to write SQL statement if i have username, password and option value for department?

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to connect to my database, but I don't know how to write my code for username, password, and also department since I have 4 option value for department itself. The 3 department which is area manager, operation manager, and management will be directed to same page, but admin is redirected to `admin.html`. How to write proper code ?

This is my `login.php`:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM login_user WHERE loginid ='$_SESSION[username]'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $dbusername   = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword   = $row['password'];
            $dbdepartment = $row['department'];
        }

        if ($username == "$dbusername" && $password == "$dbpassword" && $dbdepartment == "am") {
            // echo "you're in! <a href='form.php'>click</a> here to enter the member page";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Login Success ')
                window.location.href='form.php'
                </SCRIPT>");
        } else if ($username == "$dbusername" && $password == "$dbpassword" && $dbdepartment == "om") {
            // echo "you're in! <a href='form.php'>click</a> here to enter the member page";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Login Success ')
                window.location.href='form.php'
                </SCRIPT>");
        } else if ($username == "$dbusername" && $password == "$dbpassword" && $dbdepartment == "m") {
            // echo "you're in! <a href='form.php'>click</a> here to enter the member page";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Login Success ')
                window.location.href='form.php'
                </SCRIPT>");
        } else if ($username == "$dbusername" && $password == "$dbpassword" && $dbdepartment == "a") { // echo "you're in! <a href='admin.html'>click</a> here to enter the member page";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Login Success ')
                window.location.href='admin.html'
                </SCRIPT>");
        }

        else
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Something went Wrong')
                window.location.href='loginmain.php'
                </SCRIPT>");

    }

}
?>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<?php
    include 'login.php';
    session_start();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM login_user WHERE loginid='$_SESSION[username]'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbusername =$row['username'];
        $dbpassword =$row['password'];
        $dbdepartment =$row['department'];
    }
    ?>   
     .............
    <form action="login.php" method="post">                     
          <div class="form_settings">   

             <p><span>Username :</span><input type="username" name="username" placeholder ="username" value = "<?php echo $username;?>" /></p>
                    <p><span>Password :</span><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"  required value = "<?php echo $password;?> " /> </p>
                    <p><span>Department :</span><select name = "department" value ="<?php echo $department;?>/><option value ="am">Area Manager </option><option value ="om"> Operation Manager</option><option value ="m"> Management</option><option value = "a"> Admin </option></select></p><br>
                        <p><span>Remember Me<input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"></span></p>
                <p style="padding-top: 15px"><a href="form.php"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit" type="submit" name="name" value="LogIn" /></a></p>                                                                                                                                 
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is my `connect.php`:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "marrybrown_clean";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

This is my `form.php`:

```
<?php
    require_once ("login.php");
    include("connect.php");    
?>
```

I am trying to create **secure** login page, but most of the code online emphasizes on username and password; how to add in for department?

Comment: There are too many problems in your code. You are using mysql functions which are now deprecated and not secure to use. At least use mysqli functions. Also what are you checking by writing this condition if ($username&&$password)? And where $_SESSION[username] value is coming from?

Comment: It's worth looking into (a) SQL injection and parameterisation, (b) XSS, (c) HTTP redirections, (d) password hashing and salting.

Comment: So what is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution for your doubt.
Your code can be made secured with the htmlspecialchar(), using mysqli rather than mysql and password hashing.